# Drawing a tree diagram

Tags: trees

How do I draw the tree diagram below in Latex? I also want to label the branches the way they are in the figure.

[image]

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \rel@kern{0.8}%
    \overline{\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.2}}%
    \rel@kern{-0.2}%
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelfont=normalfont,
              labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@secnumpunct{%
      \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ % not a run-in section heading
        \@ifnotempty{#8}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \else
        \@ifempty{#8}{.}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \fi
    }%
    \@ifempty{#8}{%
      \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{%
      \ifnum#2<\@m
        \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
          \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space
        }%
      \fi
      \@seccntformat{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup #6\relax
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \@ifnotempty{#8}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       %\@addpunct.
       }%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
%begin codes for footnotes (symbols)
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myfnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \ifcase#1% 0
    \or % 1
      \dagger%   
    \or % 2
      1 
    \or % 3  
      2
    \or % 4   
      3
    \or % 5
      4
    \else % >= 6
      \@ctrerr  
    \fi
  }%   
}   
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myfnsymbol}[1]{%
  \myfnsymbolsingle{\value{#1}}%
}

% remove upper boundary by multiplying the symbols if needed
\usepackage{alphalph}
\newalphalph{\myfnsymbolmult}[mult]{\myfnsymbolsingle}{}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
  \myfnsymbolmult{\value{footnote}}%
}
%end codes for footnotes (symbols)
```

Comment: Much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Also, see [TeXample: Trees](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/) for similar diagrams. If you modify the one most similar to fill in your information as much as possible, you'll end up with a  much simpler (and more likely to be answered) question.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thanks for the link, but I was wondering how I should incorporate my codes within this document class: \documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}.

Comment: You might want to look into `tikz` (see [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/)).

Comment: Is there a meaningful difference between `amsart` and other document classes for this case? Probably not. Same with your footnote symbols and other packages. The point is: try one of the examples linked above. See how close you can get it to your desired final result, and then ask about finishing up what's missing. What you've provided comes incredibly close to a "draw this for me" question, which may get answered, may not, or may draw a fair amount of criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't read your handwriting well so I added placeholders in most nodes; if you could add them in your question, I'll update the answer.

I think you can easily use a `forest` package for this. If you want to add a label that follows the branch, then write:

```
edge label={node[midway,sloped,anchor=south]{some calc}}
```

Otherwise, remove `sloped` and replace the anchor with `anchor=west` if it goes to the right, or `anchor=east` if it goes to the left.

---

**Edit**: In order to add a caption place the figure between the tags `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`. Adding `centering` right after the first tag ensures the figure is properly centered.

After the figure but before the second tag, add `\caption{}` for your caption and then `\label{}` which must always be placed *after* the caption (for proper referencing and numbering), or at the very least inside the caption itself (see my code to see how). When you want to refer to the figure, just write the following in your regular text paragraph.

```
\cref{<label goes here>}
```

Usually it would be `\ref{}` but this one, along with the package `cleveref` adds the word `fig.` before the numbering.

One last thing: changing labels and references will need two compiles in a row for Latex to find/use the cross-references.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning}
%
\tikzset{
    full/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0, minimum size=1mm,fill=black},
    every node/.style={minimum height=5mm,font=\footnotesize}
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{forest} for tree={
        l=2cm,
        s sep=5mm
    }
%
[ ,name=root, full
    [ ,name=left, full, edge label={node[midway,sloped,anchor=south]{some calc}}
        [I can't read, name=bottomleft] ]
    [ ,name=right,full, edge label={node[midway,anchor=west]{$P+(d+)$}}
        [what you, edge label={node[midway,sloped,anchor=south]{some calc}}] 
        [wrote there, edge label={node[midway,anchor=west]{more calc}}] ] ]
%
\draw[dashed] (-2.2,0) -- (2.2,0) node[anchor=west,right] {$+ = 0$};
\draw[dashed] (-2.2,-2) -- (2.2,-2) node[anchor=west,right] {$+ = 1$};  
\node[anchor=east, left=5mm of bottomleft] {Really,};
\end{forest}
\caption{This is a caption\label{myforest}}
\end{figure}

I really enjoyed creating the forest in \cref{myforest}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I label the tree diagram as Figure 1? I tried using the caption command within the forest codes but it didn't work. I would also like to reference this Figure 1.

Comment: @user36829 Hey, I was asleep. See the edited answer, and let me know if something is not clear. :)

Comment: Is it possible to make this tree look a little bit fancy?

Comment: @user36829 It depends on what you mean by fancy. :P

Comment: Any cool templates that you could recommend?

Comment: @user36829 Again, it depends on what you mean by fancy. But any package like `forest` or `tikz` can have fancy trees.